# Patching iphone calculator.app with IDA for testing

Tags: iphone, reverse-engineering, patch, ida

I'm trying without success to patch iPhone calculator to replace the `+` function with the `-` function.
I do some stuff but when I try to launch it from my iPhone it crashes.

What I do is:

1. Opening the .app file and looking for the file that contain the code.
2. Do my work: patch it and then reload it into the phone.
3. I open calculator.app and copy my executable file in that "folder".

But it does not work and my app crashes.

I try also to rename only some string (basic patch) but the result is always the same. My App always crashes. I think that my method is not correct.

What is my error?

Comment: don't forget about code signing

Comment: Mmm maybe this is the cause of my problem! What I must do?

Comment: are you working on a jailbroken device?

Comment: yes! I'm working on a jailbroken device, any helps? any tutorial that you can suggest to me?

Answer (score 0):

after you edit the binary, you need to sign it with `ldid or ldone.` I prefer `ldone`.

To get `ldone`, add `http://cydia.hackulo.us` to your sources and install `ldone` from that source.

Then with command/ssh run:

```
ldone /Directory/of/binary -s
```

then chmod to binary to 0775 and app should open.